# Regular expression for DirectoryIndex in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Sorry if I duplicate some discussions about .htaccess. but I didn't find a direct answer to my questions.
Here they are:
1. I am trying to remove index.php from URLs in home directory and subdirectories.
So far I've come to the following two rules (one for home directory and the other for subdirectories):

```
# removes index.php (in public_html)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]

# removes index.php (in all directories exept public_html)
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/index\.php /$1 [R=301,R]
```

Is there a way to make it with one common rule?

2. I also have quite a few subdirectory-index-files with different prefixes ending with -index:
   bla-index, foo-index, prefix-index etc. I want to make them all work as DirectoryIndex using some kind of regular expression. 
   The following rule removes prefix-index.php

   ```
   #removes prefix-index.php (in all directories exept public_html)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)index.php /$1 [R=301,R]
   ```

That's exactly what I wanted but now I have the 403 error because 
htaccess says:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I've tried different regular expressions for DirectoryIndex with no success. Please help!

P.S. I can only use the htaccess not the httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `index.php` using this code in site root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*)index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```